# Is someone informed on or of characteristics?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, collocation

A friend asked me to look at their resume.  I saw this sentence:

> Ensured that referring physicians are informed on abnormalities and suggestions via letters

Is *on* the correct word to use, or is *of*?  *Of* sounds right to me, but I'm not sure.

Comment: *of* or *about*....

Comment: @Drew, is there a rule or something that I can refer to?

Comment: Broadly, if they are informed *on* something, it means they know a lot about it. If they are informed *of* something, it means someone's told them it happened.

Comment: Unfortunately, prepositions in many languages are idiomatic, so forget about sensible rules. People just learn what goes with what over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrasal verb *inform on* does exist:

> **Inform on someone**: to give information to the police or somebody in authority about the illegal activities of somebody -
> *I will inform them on you!*

However, it doesn't exactly fit into the sentence you originally posted. Physicians can't be informed on *something*. They might be informed on *someone*, but not *something*. To me, it seems incorrect.

'Of' and 'about' are both acceptable prepositions for the verb 'inform':

> Please inform us of any changes of address.
>
> The leaflet informs customers about healthy eating.
>
> He went to inform them of his decision.

[Oxford Anvanced Dictionary - Inform](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/inform)